# D3D11 CORRUPTION : CopySubresourceRegion:Sixth parameter is corrupt or NULL?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, direct3d

Decode h264 via ffmpeg d3d11va,i successfully get a frame,but when i copy resource,i got this error..

```
 ret = avcodec_receive_frame(avctx, frame);//it's OK;  
 dctx->CopySubresourceRegion(dst_resource, 0, 0, 0, 0, (ID3D11Texture2D*)frame->data[0], (int)frame->data[1],NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cast data to a `ID3D11Texture2D` interface type. You have to copy it from your frame into a instance of the texture 2D before you can use it to copy.

As the memory you are starting with is in CPU, you need to create a `USAGE_STAGING` texture, `Map`, copy the data, `Unmap`, and then you can `CopySubresourceRegion`

Comment: Thanks for your anwser,but i think d3d11va is a hardware decoder,so `frame->data[0]`  is a GPU resource.Did I understand wrong？

Comment: Apparently not with that error :)